# Why does this global variable change its value?

Tags: python

For reference: Ben is father of John, jonathan is father of benjamin.
What I am trying to end up with:

```
{'Ben': {'child': 'John'}, 'jonathan': {'child': 'benjamin'}}
```

My code:

```
main_dictionary = {}
inside_dictionary = {}
parent_key = 'Ben'
child_key = 'child'


def addtoDictionary():
    parent_key = 'jonathan'
    child_name = 'benjamin'
    main_dictionary[parent_key] = inside_dictionary # should be empty {}
    print("inside fcn: ",main_dictionary)
    main_dictionary[parent_key][child_key] = child_name # child should be "benjamin"
    print("inside fcn: ",main_dictionary)
    return()

main_dictionary[parent_key] = inside_dictionary
child_name = 'John'
main_dictionary[parent_key][child_key] = child_name #should be "Alan"
print(main_dictionary)

addtoDictionary()
```

However, what I end up with is:

```
{'Ben': {'child': 'John'}}
inside fcn:  {'Ben': {'child': 'John'}, 'jonathan': {'child': 'John'}}
inside fcn:  {'Ben': {'child': 'benjamin'}, 'jonathan': {'child': 'benjamin'}}
```

Why does "inside_dictionary" have a value of anything other than {} inside the function? I don't appear to be assigning it a value anywhere?

I found if I change the line

```
main_dictionary[parent_key] = inside_dictionary # should be empty {}
```

to

```
main_dictionary[parent_key] = {} # should be empty {}
```

I get the correct results:

```
{'Ben': {'child': 'John'}}
inside fcn:  {'Ben': {'child': 'John'}, 'jonathan': {}}
inside fcn:  {'Ben': {'child': 'John'}, 'jonathan': {'child': 'benjamin'}}
```

but I don't understand why I can't reuse the "inside_dictionary" variable? (This program, or some derivation, will ultimately use the addtoDictionary function recursively if that matters)

Comment: You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - it sounds like you're expecting "by value" semantics that Python doesn't use.

Answer (score 1):

@user2357112 is pointing you in the right direction, but here is a simple example that may help you understand the issue more clearly. When you insert a dictionary (`inside_dict`) into another dictionary (`outside_dict`) you are actually inserting a reference to the original dictionary versus a copy of it.

```
inside_dict = {}
outside_dict = {}

outside_dict["inside"] = inside_dict
outside_dict["inside"]["foo"] = "bar"

print(outside_dict)
print(inside_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'inside': {'foo': 'bar'}}
{'foo': 'bar'}
```